# Starting up processes with a window service

Tags: c#, process, windows-services, appdomain

I am asking a lot of questions today, but that because i know that you guy's are the best.
To my question, we have built a window service that starts all of our self build applications in our servers. we are doing it by

```
foreach(var path in paths)
{
  Process p = new Process(path);
  p.Start();
}
```

now.. should we recycle all of the Processes once a day?
and is t more "right" to give each process an 'appDomain' of its own ?

Comment: Could you please give more information on what you are trying to achieve by this.

Comment: actually i don't know, i am thinking of the correlation between a manager like IIS and what we are doing, and each pool has it;s own domain, maybe my question is simply my lack of knowledge. should i use new appDomain for each process.

Comment: Do you start them for e.g. testing purposes or for something else?

Comment: No there are our production programs in our servers. (we dont use windows services for that, but a console apps with no windows due to historical architecture reasons )

Comment: Does this application do anything else or is it simply a more complicated batch file?

Comment: its responsible to make sure that the programs run, and can control the restart/shutdown process with UI